# SpringBoot OAuth2 - Logout does not work allthough successful

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, keycloak, logout

I'm  experimenting with SpringBoot and Keycloak. Apparently, SprinBoot has native support for OAuth2, so it only needs a little bit of configuration.
I started with a [fresh project](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.0.7&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,oauth2-client,actuator,freemarker) and added the following properties.

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.the-client.client-id=the-client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.the-client.client-secret=Ua4A5rsk-RAr61zX-jufKcsU-XgMTVo5VeD
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.the-client.scope=openid, profile, roles
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.the-client.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.the-client.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/the-client
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.the-client.issuer-uri=http://localhost:28080/auth/realms/Project1
```

When trying to access the resources, I need to enter the password, that works. But after calling /logout, I get the successful logout page, but I still can access the protected resources.

This is a bit concerning, shouldn't that successful logout stuff only be shown when the logout really worked?

The session is not destroyed at all, I can still see it in keycloak.
What do I have to configure, that the logout works with OAuth resp. Keycloak using SpringBoot?

Answer (score 0):

The access token cannot be invalidated. You can approach this 2 solutions:

1. Decrease the access token lifespan (e.g.: set to 1 min) and keep the
   refresh token long
2. Create some sort of blacklist of the JWT, you can
   achieve this by storing the invalid JWT's(the one that logged out)
   into a DB or even better using an in-memory data cache, like Redis.